# How can i make the fields in one record in a csv file display in separated rows?

Tags: csv

I open an utf-8 encoded csv(" as quote and , as separator) file using microsoft office excel and the fields are displayed in separated rows, i did nothing and save it, when i reopen it using excel, all the fields in one record display in one row. How can i make the fields in one record display in separated rows?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option upon opening the file that you choose how you want them to be appeared. As far as I remember it's the tab option.

Comment: it seems office excel 2007 do not have the option as you said when double-click opening a csv file...

Answer (score 0):

Once your file is open in excel, and if I understand your question correctly, your wish is to transpose the data contained in the csv file.

Please read these links:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-HP010224502.aspx
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-rows-and-columns-HP010342821.aspx

HTH!

@gsvolt